# Vertex seem linked, will deform wildly if certain other vertex are moved?

Tags: vertices, mirror, geometry, mirror-modifier

I've downloaded a native blender model that somebody else created and put online and I want to make some changes to it to better suit my needs. The original creator isn't responding to messages so I can't ask them for help. The model is about 5 years old I don't know which version of blender it was created with. The model is free to use.

The original creator seems to have linked\mirrored some features, but I can't seem to find out how they did it.

I want to add more detail to the legs. Such as putting in additional folds into the fabric.

If I do a loop select on vertices on it's right leg, and then move them the corresponding vertexes on the left leg will "sort of" mirror what I'm doing on the left leg. But not exactly (They won't scale evenly, for example).

And if I try to move some of the vertex on the left side of the left foot the vertex immediately opposite it on the right hand side of the left foot will suddenly move wildly and will end up "almost" exactly where the corresponding vertex on the right side of the right food is.

It's like they made one side of the model and used mirroring to create the other side. But also used mirroring to make each leg symetrical

The model is fully rigged with an armature, but I can't see any mirror modifiers.

Any ideas.

Comment: It's going to be a lot easier to help you if you share your blend file with this model in it. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: I don't know if it's an appropriate model for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like X-mirroring was causing this. I seriously don't understand why it was having this effect but it looks like it was.

It's really weird as it was only applying it to selected parts of the model.

[image]